# Is SMB3-only Samba secure?

Tags: smb, samba

There's lots of "SMB is bad" parrotting online, and whenever I look closely, these claims are either unsubstantiated, or apply to unpached or misconfigured Windows servers or old versions of the SMB protocol.

If I put stuff like this in my [smb.conf](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html)

```
server min protocol = SMB3
smb encrypt = required
tls cafile = /letsencrypt/chain.pem
tls certfile = /letsencrypt/cert.pem
tls keyfile = /letsencrypt/key.pem
```

am I still in trouble?

Notably, Microsoft's own Azure Cloud ostensibly [offers Internet facing SMB3 shares](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/files/). So there must be a way to secure them, right? One thing that still worries me is that I've never seen Windows Explorer complain about self signed certificates.